# Native Linking Failed, Undefined symbol :

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I have a Xamarin.iOs project runs successfully. Recently I upgraded one of the Nugetpackages used in the project and I am ended up with various `Native linking failed`issues. followings are part of the errors.

[image]

What is the reason for these issues and how can I overcome these? Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you upgrade your Nugetpackages and the native linker can't find a symbol referenced somewhere. For specific solutions, you can refer to the official documentation: [MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: *. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5210-native-linking-failed-undefined-symbol--please-verify-that-all-the-necessary-frameworks-have-been-referenced-and-native-libraries-are-properly-linked-in)

Comment: Thanks... the library I updated has given a sample project and they have added Setting --gcc_flags -L/usr/lib/swift --gcc_flags -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos --gcc_flags "-Wl,-rpath -Wl,@executable_path/Frameworks"  into the mtouch arguments. Do you have an idea what is the meaning of this command?

Comment: Manually link with the required framework by passing -gcc_flags '-framework SystemFramework' to mtouch. I updated my link.